# Lazy var for playing audio when reference image is detected

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I would like to play individual audio files from reference images.

Would I use a `lazy var` to load the audio file and then use

```
func getNode(withImageName name: String)
```

to trigger which audio to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

If you wanna know how to use `SceneKit positional audio` read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044242/arkit-spatial-audio-barely-changes-the-volume-over-distance/58050226#58050226).

In case you use `RealityKit positional audio` in your app – read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230335/cant-load-audio-using-audiofileresource-loadnamed-type-method).

Let's see how your code may look like for `lazy var`:

```
 lazy var geoAndAudioNode: SCNNode = {
    
    guard let scene: SCNScene = SCNScene(named: "pixar.usdz"),
          let node: SCNNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "model", 
                                                    recursively: true)
    else { return SCNNode() }
    
    let myPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio", ofType: "mp3")
    let myURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: myPath!)
    let mySource = SCNAudioSource(url: myURL)!
    
    let audioNode = SCNNode()
    let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: mySource)
    node.addChildNode(audioNode)
    audioNode.addAudioPlayer(player)
    
    return node
}()
```

And here's how your code may look like inside `renderer` method:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
                 didAdd node: SCNNode,
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
              let imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name
        else { return }
                    
        let geometryNode = retrieveNode(name: imageName)
        node.addChildNode(geometryNode)
    }
    
    func retrieveNode(name: String) -> SCNNode {
        
        var node = SCNNode()
        
        switch name {
            case "geoAndAudioImage": node = geoAndAudioNode
            default: break
        }
        return node
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to stumble through it  with similiar code and some tutorials.  Much to learn and the posts will be helpful as well.

Comment: Should I comment on the post for scenekit positional audio here or click on the post first and then comment?

Comment: It's up to you))

Comment: Trying out the code from your post on scenekit positional audio.  Getting  "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"  on the line

Comment: "let myURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: myPath!)"  Seems as if it can't find the audio even though I loaded an audio file that plays in other projects that I have created.

Comment: Maybe your audio format is unreadable inside SceneKit?

Comment: Is readable.  I am using it in a different instance and plays fine.  I haven't used bundle before to play audio but is mono.  file names seem correct.

Comment: let myPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hail Mary prayer mono", ofType: "mp3")

        let myURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: myPath!)

        let mySource = SCNAudioSource(url: myURL)!

Comment: Please send me this file via FilesSharing resource. I'll test it.

Comment: Not sure where to upload the file.  I am assuming not PasteBin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219573/discussion-between-skynard-and-andy-fedoroff).

Comment: dropmefiles.com

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a1jbla0z9146fsp/AADNEFb3qtuzecwjrmK2FU-6a?dl=0

Comment: Thank you, I'll tell you about result.

Comment: Thank you!!  The avaudiomixing looks like a great tool to really control audio.  Hopefully it lives up to it.

Comment: AURemoteIO.cpp:1590:Start: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (561015905)
2020-08-11 16:28:52.940425-0700 wire audio[1267:753773] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1544:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode, kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)): error 561015905

Comment: I see the sphere moving but audio not playing

Comment: I had the audio set to 0.0   I apologize for such stupidity.  rookie.